# Prove that $(s-1)!(p-s)!\equiv(-1)^s \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A problem asks me to prove:

> Prove that for $0<s<p$, 
>   $$ (s-1)!(p-s)! \equiv (-1)^s \pmod p. $$

Wilson's theorem states that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

I really have no idea where to start here so any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$\eqalign{(p-s)!
  &=(p-s)(p-(s+1))\cdots(p-(p-1))\cr
  &\equiv(-1)^{p-s}s(s+1)\cdots(p-1)\pmod p\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Okay, so then I tack on the (s-1)! giving me something that looks like (-1)^(p-s) * s(s+1)(s-1)(s+2)(s-1)...(p-1) correct?

Comment: The formula you have written looks odd, I think you need to be more careful.  But your basic idea is correct.